# Pass value on styled-component within usage

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to make Header (own component) to be a styled-component. However I get

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_styled_components**.a.Header is not a function

```
class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}>
                <NavBar>
                    <Nav>
                        <NavItem>Item1</NavItem>
                        <NavItem>Item2</NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </NavBar>
            </div>
        );
    }
} 
export default Header;
```

**Desired Usage:**

```
const StyledHeader = styled.Header`
  background: ${props => props.background ||  'goldenrod'};
`;
class HomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <StyledHeader background={"#d3d9df"}/>
            <Content />
        );
    }
}
export default HomePage;
```

am I doing the right approach? **I just want different background colors for `Header` every page.**

Comment: Pass the color as a prop to the header component and make the outer div in `Header` the styled component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Header.js**

```
class HeaderUnstyled extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}>
               ...
            </div>
        );
    }
} 

const Header = styled(HeaderUnstyled)`
  background: ${props => props.background || '#aab' };
  font-size: large;
  font-family: Beirut;
  padding: 5px;
`;

 export default Header;
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import Header from '..header/Header.js';

class HomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Header />
            <Content />
        );
    }
}
export default HomePage;
```

**AboutPage.js**

```
import Header from '..header/Header.js';

class AboutPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Header background={'#fff'}/>
            <Content />
        );
    }
}
export default AboutPage;
```

this is my chosen approach for now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using the ThemeProvider then you declare a theme and just provide it in your mainApp after this has happened you can for example do, with the () syntax you extend that existing component:

```
const StyledHeader = styled(Header)`
  background: ${{{ theme }} => theme.headerBg};
`;
```

If you need any help feel free to hit me up.

Comment: is this the only way?

Comment: You can also use 

`<Header background={'#fff'}/>

const StyledHeader = styled(Header)
  background: ${props => props.background};
`;